# AngularJS - ForEach Loop

Tags: angularjs, foreach

I'm currently having a small issue with a specific loop for showing a button.

I'd like to show a 'suggestBirdname' button depending on two statements:
1. That the user isn't owner of the thread.
2. That the user has not suggested a bird yet on the thread.

This is what I currently have:

```
// Globelvariable
$scope.showSuggestionButton = false;

var currentSuggestions = res.data.birdsuggestions;
    currentSuggestions.forEach(function(suggestions) {
    if(suggestions.userId === auth.profile.user_id 
             && $scope.capture.birdname==='Unknown') {
        $scope.showSuggestionButton = false;
        } else {
           $scope.showSuggestionButton = true;
        } 
    })
```

As you can see in the above code, it goes through all my data of the current thread we are on searching through the suggestions.
As you can see, I set the default value to `$scope.showSuggestionButton = false;` seeing that it does not have to be visible unless the above statements are passed.

The problem when going through the loop is: If the current logged in user isn't the last one that posted a suggestion, the loop simply keeps going on, hence setting the statement to true.
I need a way to exit the loop once the following statements are triggered: 
`suggestions.userId === auth.profile.user_id && $scope.capture.birdname==='Unknown'`

It is probably and easy fix but I just can't seem to wrap my head around it at the moment..

Any help is much appreciated.

**For further clarification:**

Below I have a button to open a form, to post a suggestion.
Though I only want it to be visible if the statements posted above are valid.
Going through the data of the post (which has the suggestions linked to it), I want to use the loop above to show the button.

```
<span class="suggest-birdname-button" ng-if="showSuggestionButton">
                    <span popover-title="{{capture.birdname}}" popover-placement="bottom-left" popover-trigger="mouseenter"
                          popover-append-to-body uib-popover-template="birdInfoPopover.templateUrl" class="suggestion-button-text clickable"
                          ng-bootbox-title="Suggest Birdname"
                          ng-bootbox-custom-dialog
                          ng-bootbox-custom-dialog-template="/partials/model/suggestBirdname.html">Suggest Birdname <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></span>
                </span>
```

Comment: Did you try $scope.$watch?

Comment: Can you elaborate your logic?

Comment: Are you sure that your first if statement is going through correctly? I'd make sure that your first if statement is evaluating correctly before checking anything else.

Comment: We probably need some HTML/Template as currently you seem to be setting one button but also need to display more than one button.

Comment: did not get this line "The problem is, if the user is in the list, but isn't the last one who posted a suggestion, the button is still visible seeing it goes through all the suggestions and takes the last option."

Comment: @EkremKENTER No I have not

Comment: @Ted Yes it is going through the statement correctly. Though if the logged in user isn't the last one that suggested a birdname, the button becomes visible again.

Comment: @PeterS I updated the post.

Comment: @Ved updated post to clarify

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need to do is stop looping as soon as you find out that the user has already suggested a bird.

So, instead of looping on *all* the suggestions, even if you find that user has already suggested a bird, you need to break out of the loop.

I'd tweak your logic to do opposite of what you've done, i.e show suggestion by default, and hide it when you find out that the user has suggested a bird already.

```
$scope.showSuggestionButton = true;
$scope.checkedAllSuggestions = false;
var currentSuggestions = res.data.birdsuggestions;
for(var i=0; i<currentSuggestions.length;i++) {
    if(currentSuggestions[i].userId ===  auth.profile.user_id && $scope.capture.birdname==='Unknown') { 
   //is $scope.capture.birdname==='Unknown' check needed here, cause it has nothing to do with loop variables?
        $scope.showSuggestionButton = false;
        break;
    }
}
$scope.checkedAllSuggestions = true;
```

**EDIT**: You can alter your `ng-if` condition to show only when all the suggestions are processed. This will solve your initial display of button case. It may seem like a ugly hack, will update this answer when I find a better way to do it.

```
<span class="suggest-birdname-button" ng-if="showSuggestionButton && checkedAllSuggestions">
```

If you don't want to use for loop, there are other clean ways of doing this. You can use [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) for such functions.

Comment: I had this option already, though when the page gets loaded, there is a brief moment where the button is visible

Comment: @Borni Updated answer with a *hackish* way, will find a better solution and update the answer.

Comment: This already works though. I'll already mark it up as a good answer. If you find a beter solution, feel free to post it! Thanks

Comment: I had to retract the correct answer, seeing it doesn't seem to work when ```$scope.capture.birdname!=='Unknown'``` The button still seems to show.

Comment: Since the use of this check is not mentioned anywhere in description, I'm not sure how will it affect the condition. Modify the if condition as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

You should break your loop when your condition is true.

But there is an easy way with `Array.prototype.some()` method.

```
$scope.showSuggestionButton = currentSuggestions.some(function(suggestion){
  return suggestion.userId === auth.profile.user_id && $scope.capture.birdname==='Unknown';
});
```

`$scope.showSuggestionButton` value will be set as a true/false according to your if condition.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me, could you elaborate please?

Comment: @Borni I edited the answer, `$scope.showSuggestionButton` will be true or false(I wrote wrong scope variable instead of this edited because of it.). You may try this code block again.

Comment: @Borni Is your if-condition ok?, That code block if any item in your array suitable for that condition , it returns true otherwise false. I think that's what you need exactly.